# Is it possible to implement primitive distributed algorithms using Apache Thrift or WCF?

Tags: c#, apache, distributed, thrift, distributed-computing

Being relatively high-level frameworks, is it possible to implement primitive algorithms like **Ricart-Agrawala algorithm** and **Bully algorithm** in Apache Thrift or WCF?

Or, should I use plain old C# with .NET Remoting?

Comment: thrift is a RPC platform, WCF as I understand too, i.e. call-response. I dont know such algorithms (only short article in wikipedia). maybe You need kind of messaging transport A->B, B->C, C->D,A ? Of course thrift execute simple or complex methods on objects very well, my question is "what transport model You need"

Comment: @JacekCz, TCP/IP or UDP.

Comment: We speak at different levels (for example in OSI/ISO), jump from layer to layer, and hard to have common vision. Sorry, my English inst perfect, cant speak about nuances. read about publish-subscribe models, mqtt and others.

Answer (score 0):

As Jacek pointed out, both Thrift and WFC provide you with the means to build arbitrary complex things on top of it. The relationship is similar to the relationship between a web page (like SO) or a REST service, and the underlying HTTP protocol.

So the answer is clearly **yes**, but in a way you seem to ask the wrong question.